# Zend Framework - Plugins

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is the best way to start the plugin only for one action in the controller.

Supplement:

Here is a snippet of code, I want to run this plugin for testAction in IndexController

```
class MyApp_Plugin_MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        print 'hello world';
    }
}
```

I hope that this piece of code will be helpful for you Zoot

best regards

Comment: Some code might be helpful here, as well as a description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You could call the plugin directly

```
public function someAction()
{
    // The action in the controller you want the plugin to run

    $p = new Application_Plugin_Something();
    $p->doSomething();
}
```

or register it in the bootstrap and have the plugin check to see what is executing it

```
class Application_Plugin_Example extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $module     = $request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $action     = $request->getActionName();

        if ($module != 'default' && $controller != 'TheController' && $action != 'TheAction') {
            return;
        }

        // plugin code here...
    }
}

// in bootstrap

Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                       ->registerPlugin(
                           new Application_Plugin_Example()
                       );
```

In the plugin code, just replace "default" with the correct module, "TheController" and "TheAction" with the controller and action you want the plugin to run for.